# Is HTML5/JavaScript more secure than Flash/Java, as the browser becomes more like an OS?

Tags: javascript, flash, html-5, end-user

I have been asked to post this here:

I want to focus on the security of the end-user in these two different scenarios:

1) Pre HTML 5 where the applications and so on lived in plug ins outside the browser sandbox by way of Flash and Java installed and enabled.

2) Post HTML 5 and applications being moved into the browser sandbox so      you no longer need to breach the browser environment to get at this data and applications, and hooks into system hardware like cameras and so on given directly to the browser by way of HTML and JS accessible hooks built into the browser it's self.

I’m not talking about server-side security. Nor the core OS that may run the browser environment. I am referring to User Data and as the Browser becomes the OS as far as the user is concerned what they care about being safe from attack.

There is a big cry that FLASH is unsecure (and it is), and that HTML 5 is better (but will it stay that way?). As we move all the data and applications into the browsers, and add the hooks to let the web pages Java Script control hardware in the same way Flash and Java were used will that hold true? Or will the addition of these features create similar breached of privet data and loss of control of applications stored in the browser, possibly even allow remote hack of the browser as an OS setup?

While these breaches could in theory be limited to the browser level, as the Browser in effect become OS like to the end user: would the average end user distinguish those attacks from what we see now with Flash and Java? Or would they likely be perceived as the same to the average end user?

Comment: I don't know who told you to post it here, but that person seems to be unaware that we are unable to see into the future.

Comment: Your question, while quite interesting, seems a poor fit for this site. It seems likely to lead to answers that are chatty and speculative; something that is discouraged here. Perhaps you'll find https://reddit.com/r/security a better fit.

Comment: I welcome your suggestions on how to "reword"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is broad and I will try to answer part of it. In my opinion the move to the web, disabling of Flash and Java etc does not make the whole system safer. It just shifts the fragility and exploits to other kinds of attacks. While we currently have lots of attacks at the OS level  and application level (buffer overflows etc) we will have more logic and design problems in the future, which might be even cross-platform. And we can already see lots of these attacks today.

The current design of the web is insecure by default. Inside the web browser security contexts merge, that means it is possible to use the browser as a trampoline to attack internal sites from outside or similar (CSRF, DNS rebinding...). While newer features like WebSockets, WebRTC, CORS... where more designed with security in mind the insecurity of the basic design remains and the new features actually might attack add attack surface.

Attempts to harden the design focus on the transport of the data (HSTS, HPKP) or specific attacks vectors (XSS protection with CSP or some anti-XSS heuristics in the browser) and are mostly add-ones anyway, where the web application must specifically enable this protection on the server side. Content Security Policy (CSP) is actually a good example for this strategy, because it has to be explicitly added on the server side and the application has to be adapted. But at the end CSP just tries to add some security on top of the problem of merging data and code (i.e. JavaScript inline inside HTML) instead of tackling the underlying design problem. And attacks like CSRF also need to be explicitly accounted for in the application with CSRF tokens etc, because by default the application is insecure.

My prediction is that this insecurity by design will give us more of this kind of problems in the future. CSRF, XSS, SQL injection... are application layer attacks and cross-application attacks which all make use of this insecure design. And we will get more of these as long we don't tackle the underlying issues but instead expect all developers to know these problems and explicitly design their applications around the insecure basic design. Today it is easy to write insecure applications and very hard to write secure applications. It is easy to predict what you usually get.

We had such insecure design in the past in CP/M, DOS, Windows 3.1 etc where each application had very broad rights and could cause harm to other applications or even the underlying hardware. This was fixed by adding process isolation, user accounts with different permissions, DEP and lots of other techniques. These were changes to the underlying design and thus increased the security of all applications inside the OS. With the "Browser OS" we are currently at the same level of security as DOS or Windows 3.1. The only kind of (weak) isolation between web applications we have is the Same Origin Policy and this kind of protection can be easily by bypassed with XSS. Unfortunately today's "Browser OS" is exposed to a dangerous environment (the internet) much more than Windows 3.1 was. It will be a hard way to bake security into the design of the web without breaking too much but I see no other option and we should go this way fast.

Comment: I happen to largely agree with you. But I find it sad that by trying to be proactive about this as you call it "just shifts the fragility and exploits to other kinds of attacks" one tends to be attacked as an ignoramus. I do think it will  eventually get fixed, in the same way other platforms grew up with time. But as you point out "insecurity by design will give us more of this kind of problems in the future" which means unless you think about that "future" you can pretend many things. IMO no one expects the browsers to get security right on try one.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to start this post by mentioning that I expect a downvote from the OP, and possibly a flag, as this question is in fact part of an elaborate straw man which was originally an argument which resulted in my posting of [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/106689/for-an-end-user-is-html5-javascript-more-secure-than-flash/) question. No need to get into that here. But I will certainly answer the question. I would also like to note that Steffen has provided quite an informational answer. However, I would like to add to it in order to maybe clarify some things.

> 1) Pre HTML 5 where the applications and so on lived in plug ins
>   outside the browser sandbox by way of Flash and Java installed and
>   enabled.

By viewing the excellent answers provided in the link to the question above, you can clearly see the overall end-user security benefits of using interpreted languages such as HTML/JavaScript, compared to a technology such as Flash that requires at least some pre-compilation. Which brings me to:

> 2) Post HTML 5 and applications being moved into the browser sandbox
>   so you no longer need to breach the browser environment to get at this
>   data and applications, and hooks into system hardware like cameras and
>   so on given directly to the browser by way of HTML and JS accessible
>   hooks built into the browser it's self.

A big point I would like to make here, is that the vulnerabilities being found and utilized via Java and Flash have very little to do with the actual features and system resources that they have access to, and much more to do with the possibility of modifying the code between compilation and execution. I would also like to point out that modern JavaScript sandbox implementations are excellent, and continuing to improve. Node.js even provides methods in its documentation to take advantage of completely separate contexts of JavaScript sandboxes, all completely controllable by a single master script. I've used it myself, the documentation is [here](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) and it proves we that we can easily create our own secure sandboxes (at least for HTML/JS-based apps).

Now, in no way am I saying that these sandboxes can't be overcome. Software that interacts with an app in a sandbox would need to be trusted for all of the jobs it is doing, and it is indeed kind of like a weakest link in the chain type of thing. However I think apps for a futuristic WebOS would work much the same way browser plugins or add-ons work nowadays. They are usually given much more access to the system than regular webpages, but again they work off of the same interpreted-language-based technologies (unless it would be considered "native" such as with Java or Flash, in which case it would also have much more access to your computer).

> I’m not talking about server-side security. Nor the core OS that may
>   run the browser environment. I am referring to User Data and as the
>   Browser becomes the OS as far as the user is concerned what they care
>   about being safe from attack.

Java/Flash exploits are common because of the fact that there are so many ways of causing a crash by modifying its pre-compiled code before the file has a chance to be executed. A crash happens when either illegal memory is referenced within the application, or legal memory is executed, but corrupt or otherwise not in an executable format. Non-official compilers even get this to happen by accident. Taking advantage of this type of flaw to produce an exploit is usually only a matter of skill and time. By the end of it, the app doesn't even have to crash.

On the contrary, it is absolutely impossible to modify JavaScript code between the stages of compilation and execution. This makes those very exploits that are being utilized by Flash and Java inherently impossible to reproduce in JavaScript. Modifying the binary of a JavaScript file maliciously to take advantage of the way it is interpreted is made impossible due to the fact that any irregularity is picked up by the compiler as a syntax error. The entire contents of the file have to abide by strict rules based on the syntax of the language itself, otherwise not a single line will be executed. This type of check cannot be performed on pre-compiled/binary files such as those associated with Java/Flash, as that check is instead done by the compiler on the developer's machine. The client (end-user) has no such protection.

It is, however, important to note that compiled languages suffer from all of the same types of security flaws that interpreted languages suffer from. Having said that, I would also like to make it clear that any software that allows an unsolicited website to arbitrarily run code on your system will inherently come with risks. In a security context, rule number one is to minimize risk as much as possible while not affecting necessary functionality. If a vulnerability is found in Flash that lets it execute arbitrary code on the system, you consider it a system compromise. Many Flash vulnerabilities fit into this category. This is an inherent security flaw that pre-compiled code suffers from (as I explained above). Since in a future Web-based-OS we would be worrying more about XSS and CSRF vulnerabilities (which would not necessarily be considered a system compromise) than arbitrary code execution, I think it is safe to say (if anything), yes, HTML5/JavaScript will end up being more secure.

*Disclaimer: It is entirely possible for external forces to complicate the answer between now and in the future if/when Web-based operating systems actually come into effect. This is only speaking in terms of my own current knowledge pertaining to the inherent security model behind entirely interpreted and non-entirely-interpreted languages, as they compare to each other in terms of end-user security, and as it applies within the context of the question asked. This contains theoretical opinions based on the assumption that not much will change technologically speaking if/when a move is made to using Web-based operating systems.*